# How to convert bytes back to a list of integers when it has been packed using 2 bytes per int and 'big' order?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, file-io, byte

I am using converting a list of integers into bytes using the to_bytes function. As some numbers in my list are greater than 255 and can get pretty large; I arbitrarily decided to store them using 3 bytes. 
So in my loop I do the following:-

```
for number in original_array:
     byte_file_writer_delta.write(number.to_bytes(3, byteorder='big'))
```

So for example if I have a numbers like [1900, 1901] in my original array. When I convert it back using the following code, I get something like
[0, 7, 108, 0, 7, 109] in my output. **I am trying to see the numbers 1900 and 1901 when I read them back from the file.** The code I use to read back the numbers is:

```
byte_file_reader= open('byte_file_inverted_index.txt', 'rb')
byte_file_reader.seek(byte_offset)
mybytes=byte_file_reader.read(byte_size)
print(list(mybytes))
```

Comment: What's your `byte_offset`? How do you calculate it? How does it correlate to the position of the bytes written from `original_array`?

Answer (score 0):

See if the following script may somehow help you... I believe the bytes_to_int function will do just fine for you!

i've used a few numbers for testing (original_array)

```
original_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,1500,2999,50000,789456,9999999]

def bytes_to_int(bytes):
    result = 0
    for b in bytes:
        result = result * 256 + int(b)
    return result

for number in original_array:
    enc = number.to_bytes(3, byteorder='big')
    print(enc)
    dec = bytes_to_int(enc)
    print(dec)
```

Comment: Thank you!

Your code is helpful but here is my issue,
I do not have access to the original_array after I dump it as bytes in a file. So basically I have to get that list back from the file and decode it. Hence, I can't really use the line dec= bytes_to_int(enc) because I have no access to the individual enc (numbers) after I read the file back. It is just a chunk of bytes from which I need to extract individual numbers.

Comment: I figured out the rest! Thank you! :)

Comment: `byte_file_reader= open('byte_file_inverted_index.txt', 'rb')


 byte_file_reader.seek(byte_offset)


 mybytes=byte_file_reader.read(byte_size)

 array1 = []


 while len(mybytes)>0:
 character = mybytes[:3]
 array1.append(bytes_to_int(character))
 mybytes=mybytes[3:]


return array1
`
I am using your function in iteration. I think this does it right. :)